# Is it possible to install LAN Messenger on CentOS 7?

Tags: centos

I am trying to install LAN Messenger on CentOS 7 (64bit) using following command:

```
yum install lmc-1.2.32-2.i386.rpm
```

That file was downloaded from https://github.com/lanmessenger/lanmessenger/releases

But i am getting following error:

```
Transaction check error:
  file /usr/bin from install of lmc-1.2.32-2.i386 conflicts with file from package filesystem-3.2-21.el7.x86_64
  file / from install of lmc-1.2.32-2.i386 conflicts with file from package filesystem-3.2-21.el7.x86_64
  file /usr/lib from install of lmc-1.2.32-2.i386 conflicts with file from package filesystem-3.2-21.el7.x86_64
```

Is it possible to solve this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use

```
rpm -ivh --replacefiles foo-1.0-1.i386.rpm
```

This will replace those conflicting files with the new ones.

PS. **You really need to do this on a virtual server, not your production server first** since there are files in `/` that will be replaced, and you need to see which of them are.

Comment: The command went good but when i finally launch lan messenger using `lmc` it did not launch with following error:

 `This is not a Canonical "designed" product.
/usr/lib/lmc/lan-messenger: error while loading shared libraries: libaudio.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

Comment: That's probably because the rpm package is not updated, or has a bad dependency tree. Try to search for libaudio and install it, if that doesn't solve the issue, you'll need to make more tests.

Comment: Do you think following page is right for libaudio package ? https://centos.pkgs.org/7/nux-dextop-x86_64/nas-libs-1.9.4-1.el7.nux.x86_64.rpm.html

Comment: well, that provides the shared library indeed, but I'd search in lmc documentation to see if there is a particular version of libaudio needed.

Comment: now i am getting this error:  `Unable to load library icui18n "Cannot load library icui18n: (libicui18n.so.48: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)"`

Comment: You need to do the same process till you don't have errors... But I'd suggest you to fill a bug  report wherever you got that rpm...Obviously it is not being maintained...

Comment: Ok, thanks, so this way the i386 (32 bit) version of lmc will work, But i am also considering if it is possible to install the latest version of lmc (which is 64bit) ?, i am getting different error when installing 64bit rpm. lmc-x64 rpm is asking for openssl verion 1.0.0 but centos7 using higher version of openssl.